# Using Map.remove and a list of keys

Tags: f#

I'm having a hard time incorporating `Map.remove` with a list of keys.

For example, if I have

```
let z : Map<int, Set<int>> = Map.ofList [(1, set []); (3, set [3; 4]); (4, set [])]
```

and I want to programmaticaly find each `key, value` in which the `value` is empty, I can do this:

```
let emptySets = 
    z
    |> Map.toList
    |> List.map (fun (k, s) -> (k, s |> Set.toList |> List.length))
    |> List.filter (fun (k, i) -> i = 0)
    |> List.map fst
```

This gives me

```
[1; 4]
```

which is exactly what I was expecting.  But now, if I want to remove those `key, value` pairs from the map, the only way I can think of to do this is to convert the original `Map` into a list like this:

```
z
|> Map.toList
|> List.filter (fun (k, s) -> not (emptySets 
                                   |> List.contains k))
```

This gives me back the map I was expecting.

When I do this

```
emptySets
|> List.map (fun i -> Map.remove i z)
```

I get back a list of Maps.

Is there a way that I can use `Map.remove` to remove a list of keys from a given map *without* getting back a list of maps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every `Map.remove` call returns you a new `map` - identical to the "old" one, but without that one item. The old map is still intact, you can still use it, but if you continue to use it, you will still see the removed item, because it's still in the old map. If you want to perform next operations without the removed item, you have to perform those operations on the "new" map - the one returned from `Map.remove`, the one not containing the item.

```
let m0 = // create the map
let m1 = Map.remove 1 m0
let m2 = Map.remove 4 m1
```

Notice how each operation uses the result of the previous one. When you have a whole list of such operations, where each next one must use the result of the previous, thus "accumulating" the result in a sense, - that's called `fold`. The `fold` function takes three things: the initial accumulated value, a function that takes previous value and produces the next one, and the list of inputs:

```
let mapFinal= List.fold (fun mapPrev key -> Map.remove key mapPrev) mapInitial keys
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  I had been thinking that `fold` may be the way to go but couldn't figure out exactly how to set it all up.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I missed some point but couldn't it be easier to simply use `Map.filter` to keep the items where the value set isn't empty rather than removing all items where the value set is empty ?

Also it's a lot simpler to use `Set.isEmpty` rather than converting to list get it's length and checking if it's 0 or not.

```
Map.filter (fun _ -> not << Set.isEmpty) z
// val it : Map<int,Set<int>> = map [(3, set [3; 4])]
```

Comment: Good point. But I thought this was a great moment to explain fold.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a fold:

```
let z : Map<int, Set<int>> = Map.ofList [(1, set []); (3, set [3; 4]); (4, set [])]
let keysToRemove = [1;2]
List.fold (fun x i -> Map.remove i x) z keysToRemove

// val it : Map<int,Set<int>> = map [(3, set [3; 4]); (4, set [])]
```